# What is the best Google Chrome extension for Delicious?

Tags: google-chrome, delicious, google-chrome-extensions

I use a Chrome extension which works very well with Google Bookmarks, allowing syncing with local bookmarks and easy adding and reference to existing Google bookmarks.

The Delicious extension that I am currently using only offers an easy way to make bookmarks, but not use existing ones.

Does anybody have any better Chrome extensions for Delicious?  It looks like there are quite a few, so I am looking for recommendations.

Comment: I use Pocket instead these days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### [Delicious Bookmarks Extension (Beta)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mnaelnkmidnndgikjbiifihgklnocljd)

Delicious Bookmarks is the official Google Chrome extension for Delicious.

This extension has the support to add new bookmarks as well as search existing book marks.

Comment: Ah, I did see that before of course, but I did not realise that it could search existing bookmarks through the address bar.  It's still not quite as good as the unofficial Google Bookmarks addon that I use, but it works fine and will do, unless anybody comes up with any better ones.

Comment: It requires the permission to access "Your data on all websites" - too intrusive.

Answer (score 7):

As of May 2012, the recommended tool (according to the owner - AVOS) for using Delicious in the browser is via [the bookmarklet](http://delicious.com/tools). This was announced in a blog post ([Update on the browser extensions](http://blog.delicious.com/2012/01/update-on-the-browser-extensions/)) from January 15, 2012. The reason is that the company has decided to focus on improving the service and providing the best possible experience across all browsers, but does not feel that the effort of maintaining extensions for all browsers can be justified at this time. The blog post also mentions bugs and feature discrepancies between the extensions for various browsers which would require significant effort to resolve.